# figuring out which onclick event youre using and sending that to a handler

Tags: javascript, php, database, forms, pdo

To be honest i got my login/sign up form from online. I have dealt with a little bit of javascript but the one its using is a bit above my head. So what i'd like to do is figure out which onclick event im using and be able to send that to another function in my handler to log them in instead of signing them up. Is that possible? And if so where can i find information on how to do it?

```
<div class="cont_principal">

    <div class="cont_centrar">
        <div class="cont_login">
            <form action="handlercreate.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="cont_tabs_login">
                    <ul class='ul_tabs'>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="sign_in()">SIGN IN</a><span class="linea_bajo_nom"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="#up" onclick="sign_up()">SIGN UP</a><span class="linea_bajo_nom"></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="cont_text_inputs">
                    <input value = "<?php echo isset($presets['display_name']) ? $presets['display_name'] : ''; ?>" type="text" class="input_form_sign " placeholder="DISPLAY NAME" id = "display_name" name="display_name" />
                    <input value = "<?php echo isset($presets['email']) ? $presets['email'] : ''; ?>"type="text" class="input_form_sign d_block active_inp" placeholder="EMAIL" id = "email" name="email"/>
                    <input type="password" class="input_form_sign d_block  active_inp" placeholder="PASSWORD" id = "password" name="password" />  
                    <input type="password" class="input_form_sign" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD" id = "confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" /><a href="#" class="link_forgot_pass d_block" >Forgot Password ?</a>    
                </div>
                <div class="cont_btn">
                    <button class="btn_sign" type="submit" value="Submit">SIGN IN</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to also pass that value to my handler so i can have it us that value to ignore certain calls.

JavaScript

```
    function sign_up(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input_form_sign');
    document.querySelectorAll('.ul_tabs > li')[0].className=""; 
    document.querySelectorAll('.ul_tabs > li')[1].className="active"; 
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++  ) {
    if(i == 2  ){

        }else{  
        document.querySelectorAll('.input_form_sign')[i].className = "input_form_sign d_block";
        }
    } 

    setTimeout( function(){
    for(var d = 0; d < inputs.length ; d++  ) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.input_form_sign')[d].className = "input_form_sign d_block active_inp";  
    }
    },100 );
    document.querySelector('.link_forgot_pass').style.opacity = "0";
    document.querySelector('.link_forgot_pass').style.top = "-5px";
    document.querySelector('.btn_sign').innerHTML = "SIGN UP";    

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.terms_and_cons').style.opacity = "1";
        document.querySelector('.terms_and_cons').style.top = "5px";
    },500);

    setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.link_forgot_pass').className = "link_forgot_pass d_none";
    document.querySelector('.terms_and_cons').className = "terms_and_cons d_block";
    },450);

}


function sign_in(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input_form_sign');
    document.querySelectorAll('.ul_tabs > li')[0].className = "active"; 
    document.querySelectorAll('.ul_tabs > li')[1].className = ""; 
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++  ) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            console.log(inputs[i].name);
        break;
        case 2:
            console.log(inputs[i].name);
        default: 
            document.querySelectorAll('.input_form_sign')[i].className = "input_form_sign d_block";
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty confused on what you want to happen. What’s the end result you want? Also, please include the relevant JavaScript code!

Comment: Sorry i wasnt sure if it would really help in my case. Im passing my arguments to my handler however when i use sign in instead of sign up it still wants all the values you would normally add such as display name and confirm password. I would like to be able to second another argument depending on if they are using the sign up or sign in form so that i can handle their submit differntly

Comment: End result is i want to be able to account for not having information in the 2 other non visible forms when you use sign in so that i can handle that submit and send them to the correct page since they already have an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you experience with Javascript, so I will break down how I would handle this. Hopefully it works out for you.

First we need to grab your button from the DOM.

```
var buttonEventhandler = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_sign');
```

getElementsByClassName will grab every instance of the class
you pass it, and store it in an array. So from here we will
setup a handler for all buttons with that class. If you just want it on a single button, give it a special class or data attribute so you can find it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttonEventhandler.length; i++) {
    buttonEventhandler[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // you can stop the form from firing, unless your
    // certain conditions are met. For now I will just use the event
    if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Now that the default form event is canceled, do your thing...
        e.target.innerHTML = 'TRY AGAIN';
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tjz11mqg/9/

if you want to see the form function normally, just change the condition to !e.

```
// like this:
if (!e) {
```

Useful links if you want to learn more about how this works:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

adding a note: I was writing this before seeing your JS, so possibly expect an update.

Comment: thanks that helps me understand what i want to do to a degree. However the class name changes depending on which button is active. Is there a way i can use the address as a trigger instead. Since for one the address ends in # and the other in #up?

Comment: or use the function call from onclick? where one is sign in and the other sign up

Comment: After reading through your past explination, I want to make sure I understand the scenario better:
You have multiple forms on a page.
One redirects to /#
the other redirects to /#up
On submission of the sign-in, it's checking for problems in the other sign-up form?

Comment: So the html is setup so there is only 4 form entries. Depending on if you click on "sign in" or "sign up" Only 2 are visible or all 4. What im trying to do is maybe pass another value to my handler that if the form was sent using the sign up one that it only requires two inputs, otherwise expect 4

Comment: my handler is set up to check four inputs from the form, which if im able to send another value depending on what onclick( event) im using then i can fix the issue

Comment: Not sure what your handler is looking for, but can you not just do things conditionally based on the data you're given? If(username && password && otherfield && otherfield) { // do something } elseif(username && password) { // do something else } else { // error state }

Comment: Thanks but i went a different route. But i could do that but its a big safety issue. So since i dont know javascript well enough im ignoring it and just making two different forms

Answer (score 0):

Henkers's code will work, but is not well-optimized for performance. With [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/aaronr/tjz11mqg/34/), the main difference is this:

```
signInButton.addEventListener('click', signInEventHandler);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronr/tjz11mqg/34/

...where `signInEventHandler` is a function with a single parameter for the event object. Passing a function to the event listener allows the listener to have a special signature that makes it possible to remove and hopefully be optimized by the JavaScript engine:

```
signInButton.removeEventListener('click', signInEventHandler);
```

---

Another option, if you're already using jQuery, is to have 1 event handler that checks for the element class:

```
$('form').on('click', '.js-sign-in', signInEventHandler);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronr/tjz11mqg/39/

---

NOTE: This is not as important, but it's good practice that, when you use an HTML class in JavaScript, prefix it by js- (such as `js-sign-in`). This way, when you're applying CSS, you don't accidentally change a class name that JavaScript requires, breaking functionality.

NOTE: `addEventListener` is not supported in IE10 and older (if that matters to you). Check its browser compatibility on this neat website: https://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener